# Is there a way to navigate in-between bottom navigator pages while also switching to the item

Tags: flutter, dart, materialpageroute, cupertinotabbar

I would like to navigate from one bottom navigator item to another. I would like to navigate from a page inside a specific item to another one while also switching to the other bottom navigator item page unlike the usual when it would just go onto the other pages and appear on the same bottom item. I hope its clear.

I tried navigating normally but it just keeps me in the same tab and not push me to the other bottom item tab